# Highlight Line Azure DevOps Repository

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request

In GitHub, there is an option to highlight a specific line or a number of lines in the repository.

[For example](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/356b27684e975fe718111a0d60e8d9c963a75857/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web/AuthorityHelpers.cs#L9-L11)

Is there anyway to do this in Azure Devops. When reviewing a Pull Request, it would be handy to identify an example of another file in the repository (or another repository) so that you can offer guidance to the user rather than a Link and then please look at Line 123.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Azure devops repo you can achieve the similar effect too.

You can click your mouse and hold to select the lines in the repository. Then you can copy the link of the selected lines and share it with your users. The user will see the selected lines highlighted. See below:

[image]

Comment: is it possible to have two separate lines highlighted?